# Read an already opened file using FileReader

Tags: android, webserver, filereader

My android app opens up a ZIM File stored on device. The ZIM File has multiple HTML pages in it. I want to read the text from a single HTML page. The HTML page cannot be accessed directly with it's filePath but the ZIM file could be.

For example:
`/storage/emulated/0/Download/wikipedia_en_ray_charles_2018-10.zim`

Since there's no filePath for the HTML page to open it directly. The only way to read text from it as per my knowledge would be while it's opened in the app. So, my question is that if there is any way I could read text from a HTML page while it's already opened in the app and there's no way to access it(AFAIK).

The only thing I'm getting for the HTML page is it's name combined with the content uri.

`content://org.kiwix.kiwixmobile.zim.base/Ray_Charles.html`

But this couldn't be accessed from the device.

Here's the code I've written that works for HTML files on device which have a file path.
`

```
String answer = "";
try {
  FileReader index = new FileReader(selectedFilePath);
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(index);
  String line = "";
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    answer += line;
  }
  reader.close();
```

`

Comment: It would appear that you would need to use [Zimlib](https://wiki.openzim.org/wiki/OpenZIM) or create your own clone of that library.